# Database schema of video (item) having multiple categories

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I have designed schema for web application that stores videos and each video comes under some categories.Single video can have multiple categories.I create following relations..

RELATION1:
video_detail(v_id,v_name,v_details);

RELATION2:
video_category(cat_id,cat_name);

Now i want to relate each video in *video_details*  to  *video_category* ..
I have following option:-
create relation for each category like *cat_entertainment(v_id)* and so on...

Is it efficient way for doing this work...Or there is another way to do same without redundancy, thank you ..??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that one video can have many categories and a category can be set for any number of videos, you need a bridge table called something like `video_detail_category` which will contain:

```
video_detail_category(v_id, cat_id, primary key (v_id, cat_id))
```

Comment: Okay I got it..While searching videos with advance options like check-boxes for categories how should query DB..select from video_details for all match found..and matching their v_id with cat_id???